# Java: Implementing generic Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I'm learning design patterns from 'Head First' series. The book is a bit outdated (no generic types ), so I'm trying to rewrite some of it. I'm supposed to write **Wrapper** on `Iterator` to work like `Enumerator` methods **and test it with ArrayList**.

The "original" version looked like this(below). I've tried to make it generic class such as `<E>` or even `<T<E>>`, but it didn't work. I want to be also sure that it will work for any kind of iterator, not only `ArrayList` like `ArrayList<T>`. What is the proper way to implement this ?

```
public class IteratorWrapper implements Enumeration {
    Iterator iterator;

    public IteratorWrapper(Iterator iterator){
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreElements(){
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    //Return generic Type T 
    public Object nextElement(){
        return iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Test class

```
public class WrapperTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("element1");
        arrayList.add("element2");

        //This part will be rewritten when wrapper will work  
        IteratorWrapper iteratorWrapper = new IteratorWrapper(arrayList.iterator());

        while(iteratorWrapper.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(iteratorWrapper.nextElement());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a generic parameter like this:

```
public class IteratorWrapper<T> implements Enumeration<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator;

    public IteratorWrapper(Iterator<T> iterator){
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreElements(){
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public T nextElement(){
        return iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Then, your initialization will look like this:

```
IteratorWrapper<String> iteratorWrapper = new IteratorWrapper<String>(arrayList.iterator());
```

Comment: Strange... I tried the exact copy of this, but It threw me error. I guess the problem was in creating object and passing iterator to it. Btw. I tried also this `IteratorWrapper<ArrayList<String>> iteratorWrapper = new IteratorWrapper<ArrayList<String>>(arrayList.iterator());` and It works - but... is it also proper way to init my object ?

Comment: @ashur: No; your iterator is not returning ArrayLists.  Read the compiler warnings.

Comment: It doesn't compile with Eclispe and Java 6. Anyway the point is that your wrapper (and the iterator) don't have to know that the iterator comes from an ArrayList, so the generic type doesn't need to mention ArrayList